# Y-axis values not displaying correctly in double bar graph

Tags: python, csv, data-visualization, bar-chart, yaxis

Don't know why this error is coming . pls check this. Thanks in advance.

coding->

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def dbargraph():
    df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\Bhuwan Bhatt\Desktop\IP PROJECT\olymp_data.csv',encoding='cp1252')
    df.sort_values(by='TotalMedal',ascending=False,inplace=True)
    df1=df.head(n=10)
    x=np.arange(len(df1))
    Countries=df1['Country']
    Summermedal=df1['SummerTotal']
    Wintermedal=df1['WinterTotal']
    plt.bar(x-0.2,Summermedal,label='Total Medals won by Top 10 Countries IN SUMMER',width=0.4,color='orangered')
    plt.bar(x+0.2,Wintermedal,label='Total Medals won by Top 10 Countries IN WINTER',width=0.4,color='grey')
    plt.xticks(x,Countries,rotation=20)
    plt.title('Olmypic Medal Analysis by Top 10 Countries',color='navy',fontsize=16)
    plt.xlabel('Countries~~~~>',fontsize=12,color='r')
    plt.ylabel('No. of Medals~~~~>',fontsize=12,color='r')
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()   
dbargraph()
```

error: y-axis values not displaying properly

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsCUv.png]

Answer (score 1):

did you try
to set it manually by set_yticks() ?
Im not sure if you won't need to set up the axis, i.e

axes = plt.axes()

and then specify the range of x and y ticks. That may help

Comment: can u pls make your changes in the above coding i've shown , then paste it

Comment: I'd start just from trying to add one more line, below

plt.bar(x+0.2,Wintermedal,label='Total Medals won by Top 10 Countries IN WINTER',width=0.4,color='grey')
plt.xticks(x,Countries,rotation=20)

add 
 
plt.yticks(y)

where y is max number of medals or maybe max + 20 or something like that